# Solving multiple phase angles for multiple equations

Tags: matlab, octave, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I have several equations and each have their own individual frequencies and amplitudes. I would like to sum the equations together and adjust the individual phases, phase1,phase2, and phase3  to keep the total amplitude value of eq_total under a specific value like 0.8.  I know I can normalize the signal or change the vertical offset, but for my purposes I need to have the amplitude controlled by changing/finding the values for just the phases in phase1,phase2, and phase3 that will limit the maximum amplitude when the equations are summed.

Note: I'm using constructive and destructive phase interference to adjust the maximum amplitude of the summed equations.

```
Example:
eq1=0.2*cos(2pi*t*3+phase1)+vertical offset1
eq2=0.7*cos(2pi*t*9+phase2)+vertical offset2
eq3=0.8*cos(2pi*t*5+phase3)+vertical offset3

eq_total=eq1+eq2+eq3
```

Is there a way to solve for phase1,phase2, and phase3 so that the amplitude of the summed signals in eq_total never goes over 0.8 by just adjusting/finding the values of phase1,phase2,and phase3?

Here's a picture of a geogebra applet I tested this idea with.

[image]

Here's the geogebra ggb file I used to edit/test idea with. (I used this to see if my idea would work) Java is required if you want to dynamically interact with the applet
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/ggb/sin_find_phases_example.ggb

I'm using matlab/octave
Thanks

Comment: are you sure that's what you mean? cos({integer} * 2pi + offset) == cos(offset)

Comment: I added a picture and a link to a dynamic geogebra file in the original question that should explain this easier.

Comment: Is there some additional objective you'd like to achieve other than limiting the maximum amplitude?

Comment: No at the moment I'm just trying to limit the maximum amplitude of the sum of the equations.  Granted if another limit is needed I can limit the max amplitude between 0.75 and 0.80.

Answer (score 1):

Your example

```
eq1=0.2*cos(2pi*t*3+phase1)+vertical offset1
eq2=0.7*cos(2pi*t*9+phase2)+vertical offset2
eq3=0.8*cos(2pi*t*5+phase3)+vertical offset3

eq_total=eq1+eq2+eq3
```

where the maximum amplitude should be less than 0.8, has infinitely many solutions. Unless you have some additional objective you'd like to achieve, I suggest that you modify the problem such that you find the combination of phase angles that has a maximum amplitude of *exactly* 0.8 (or 0.79, such that you're guaranteed to be below).

Furthermore only two out of three phase angles are independent; if you increase all by, say, `pi/3`, the solution still holds. Thus, you have only two unknowns in `eq_total`.

You can solve the nonlinear optimization problem using e.g. [FMINSEARCH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html). You formulate the problem such that `max(abs(eq_total(phase1,phase2)))` should equal 0.79.

Thus:

```
%# define the vector t, verticalOffset here

%# objectiveFunction is (eq_total-0.79)^2, so the phase shifts 1 and 2 that
%# satisfy this (approximately) should guarantee that signal never exceeds 0.8
objectiveFunction = @(phase)(max(abs(0.2*cos(2*pi*t+phase(1))+0.7*cos(2*pi*t*9+phase(2))+0.8*cos(2*pi*t*5)+verticalOffset)) - 0.79)^2;
%# search for optimal phase shift, starting at no shift
solution = fminsearch(objectiveFunction,[0;0]);
```

**EDIT**

> Unfortunately when I Try this code and plot the results the maximum amplitude is not 0.79 it's over 1. Am I doing something wrong? see code below t=linspace(0,1,8000); verticalOffset=0; objectiveFunction = @(phase)(max(abs(0.2*cos(2*pi*t+phase(1))+0.7*cos(2*pi*t*9+phase(2))+0.8*cos(2*p‌​i*t*5)+verticalOffset)) - 0.79)^2; s1 = fminsearch(objectiveFunction,[0;0]) eqt=0.2*cos(2*pi*t+s1(1))+0.7*cos(2*pi*t*9+s1(2))+0.8*cos(2*pi*t*5)+verticalOffs‌​et; plot(eqt)

`fminsearch` will find a minimum of the objective function. Whether this solution satisfies all your conditions is something you have to test. In this case, the solution given by `fminsearch` with the starting value `[0;0]` gives a maximum of ~1.3, which is obviously not good enough. However, when you plot the maximum for a range of phase angles from 0 to 2pi, you'll see that `fminsearch didn't get stuck in a bad local minimum. Rather, there is no good solution at all (z-axis is the maximum).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I Try this code and plot the results the maximum amplitude is not 0.79 it's over 1.   Am I doing something wrong? see code below

t=linspace(0,1,8000);
verticalOffset=0;
objectiveFunction = @(phase)(max(abs(0.2*cos(2*pi*t+phase(1))+0.7*cos(2*pi*t*9+phase(2))+0.8*cos(2*pi*t*5)+verticalOffset)) - 0.79)^2;
s1 = fminsearch(objectiveFunction,[0;0])
eqt=0.2*cos(2*pi*t+s1(1))+0.7*cos(2*pi*t*9+s1(2))+0.8*cos(2*pi*t*5)+verticalOffset;
plot(eqt)

Comment: @RickT: All you're doing wrong is to assume that the best solution is good enough. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to find a *phase* to vary the *amplitude* of a signal. To my knowledge, this is not possible.
For a signal

```
s = A * cos (w*t + phi)
```

only `A` allows you to change the amplitude. With `w` you change the frequency of the signal and `phi` regulates the "horizontal shift".

Furthermore, I think you are missing a "moving variable" like the time `t` in the equation above.

Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) article clarifies things a little.

Comment: you can use phase changes to alter the amplitude of a signal it's called constructive and destructive interference.  I posted a picture and a link to a geogebra applet in the original question that will show this

Answer (score 0):

If you set all the vertical offsets to be equal to -1, then it solves your problem because each `eq#` will never be > 0, so the sum can never be >0.8.

I know that this isn't that helpful, but I'm hoping that this will help you understand your problem better.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it needs to be done using phase changes if I use vertical offset this just shifts the signal down.  In the end these signals will be converted to audio so just shifting will cause audio clipping.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you remove the vertical offsets from the example in your question.